# Using Python to Iterate over a dataset rows part simultaneously

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am looking for directions to iterate over 100K+ rows and two columns of a dataset (CSV or Google sheet) partly simultaneously, but with a delay.

The task is to perform an API request using each row data, with a returned API response ID saved in a third column (iterating over 100K+ rows is expected to take a few hours).

With an eye on time saving, I would interested to know if it is possible/suitable to launch a second API request using request ID information saved in the third column (from the first request - which is likely still populating further down the dataset) but with a delay of around 10 minutes (ten minutes allows a task on a remote device to complete, triggered from the first API request), rather than wait for all 100K+ rows to complete before running the second API request across all rows (second API request checks if the task from the first request is complete).

I'm looking for directions at this stage before I get too far down the road with one particular method, thanks

Comment: IIUC you're sending a sequential http API requests using row data and getting response ID back. If you mean to accumulate some specific response ids and select previously processed rows by them, to re-send the request in parallel - yes, it's possible, but why making a duplicated request and what to do with delayed response?

Comment: Why not do the API requests for each row "back to back"?

Comment: Hi, normally I would've done API requests back to back for each row, but the first API request triggers a task on a remote device, which takes up to 10 mins to finish (its task), the second API is basically checking the task is done, so a follow up API request ten minutes later, seemed to make the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

Well maybe you could use Thread from threading module

It's easier to write a code then explain it in words so:

```py
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep


def function(minutes):
    sleep(60*minutes) # will wait for minutes you define
    # your code for second API request


Thread(target=function, # take an function 
       args=(10,) # Pass in the arguments
       ).start() # start a function

# If your main code stops code will wait for it to end
# and then it will end the program

# Elsely if you want to end when main program ends 

Thread(target=function, # take an function 
       args=(10,), # Pass in the arguments
       daemon=True
       ).start() # start a function

# With this when main program ends the Thread will be forced to end.
```

See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects) for Thread

---

If you want to process a dataset which cannot be changed simultaneously then I would use simple creating file and checking if file exists

```py
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import os
from random import uniform


def function(minutes):
    sleep(60*minutes) # will wait for minutes you define
    # your code for second API request
    # now if you want to change dataset check if file exists


    while os.path.isfile('RUNNING'):
        sleep(uniform(0.5, 1.5))
        # sleep with random number, because Threads would leave
        # loop at the same time and the in next line open() function
        # would raise error: FileExixts, because all of the Threads
        # would want to create same file


    # if not create it
    open('RUNNING', 'x')
    # work with dataset
    os.remove('RUNNING') # remove file

    # This is good if you want to have 2 or more functions
    # to work on something that cannot be done simultaneously
    # because it prevent it


Thread(target=function, # take an function 
       args=(10,) # Pass in the arguments
       ).start() # start a function
```

Comment: Thanks for your post, code is easier to explain sometimes.  Certainly threading is a route to follow, my only worry is how this is handled when both threads will be reading from the same dataset (albeit 10 minutes later with the second API request)

Comment: You could create an file when processing dataset and when it's done delete it, and if file exist wait for it to delete.

Comment: I did it in my SQL code in python because I can't use 2 commands at one time and i had 100 Threads, but if you have more than one Thread I would use where you check for file if exists and put there sleep with random number, preferably, number eg. `random.uniform(0.5,1.5)`